# PopupWindow does not show as expected

Tags: android

I am trying to create and display a `PopupWindow`:

```
private void setupPopupWindow() {
    TextView popTextView = new TextView(this);
    popTextView .setText("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(popTextView );
    mPopupWindow.setTouchable(true);
    mPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(anotherViewInMyActivity, Gravity.CENTER, 120, 120);
}
```

But the `popupwindow` does not show.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set size for your `TextView`.

```
setWidth(120);
setHeight(120);
```

If popup window will ignore outside touches, just set background

```
setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
```